# What am I doing wrong? Joins again?

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

Okay, I've perused this site, a couple that members here have suggested, sql textbooks, etc.
The problem:
    List customer name, order date, number ordered, quoted price, amount billed and description for items ordered from Premiere Products.  Organize this report by order date with customer name
The tables:

```
SQL> desc customer
 Name
 ----------------------
 CUSTOMER_NUM
 CUSTOMER_NAME
 STREET
 CITY
 STATE
 ZIP
 BALANCE
 CREDIT_LIMIT
 REP_NUM

SQL> desc orders
 Name
 ----------------------
 ORDER_NUM
 ORDER_DATE
 CUSTOMER_NUM

SQL> desc order_line
 Name
 ----------------------
 ORDER_NUM
 PART_NUM
 NUM_ORDERED
 QUOTED_PRICE

SQL> desc part
 Name
 ----------------------
 PART_NUM
 DESCRIPT
 ON_HAND
 CLASS
 WAREHOUSE
 PRICE
```

Here's what I am using for a query:

```
SQL>  SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, ORDERS.ORDER_DATE,
  2   ORDER_LINE.NUM_ORDERED, ORDER_LINE.QUOTED_PRICE,
  3   SUM(Num_Ordered*Quoted_Price) AS Amt_Billed,
  4   PART.DESCRIPT
  5   FROM customer
  6   INNER JOIN CUSTOMER INNER JOIN ORDERS ON
             CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM =ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM
  7   INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE ON ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM
  8   Inner JOIN ORDER_LINE ON PART.PART_NUM = ORDER_LINE.PART_NUM;
 Inner JOIN ORDER_LINE ON PART.PART_NUM = ORDER_LINE.PART_NUM
                                                            *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Ive tried it several times, even made an access table for it, and the SQL there is basically the same as what I have here. I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: forgot:   List customer name, order date, number ordered, quoted price, amount billed and description for items ordered from Premiere Products.  Organize this report by order date with customer name.

Comment: Why don't you write your queries iteratively step by step? If you did that you would know what exact part introduced a error. What you did instead - implemented a "long" messy query without understanding how it should work and how to debug it. Not efficient, is it?

Comment: does my answer below answer you question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting your SQL formatted helps follow the relationships between the tables.  Notice my simplified indentation and showing the left-side table joined to the right-side and the ON clause shows columnar relation between them.

Once that is done, then get the rest of your columns for selection, summation, group by, order by, etc

```
SELECT
      c.customer_name,
      o.order_date,
      ol.num_ordered,
      ol.quoted_price,
      ol.num_ordered * ol.quoted_price as amt_Billed,
      p.descript
   from
      customer c
         join orders o
            ON c.customer_num = o.customer_num
            join order_line ol
               ON o.order_num = ol.order_num
               join part p
                  ON ol.part_num = p.part_num
   order by
      o.order_date,
      c.customer_name
```

Since your query is showing the amount per line item of things ordered, you dont need a "SUM()", you can just multiply the columns outright as a per-line total amount as you are showing each part actually ordered.

Also notice the simplified alias name references of each table vs writing full length of each table name repeatedly.

Comment: @BrianWilson, Glad it worked, and no it is not necessary to indent, yet it visually helps you follow where things are going to.  What if you had another table for customer by country... that has no bearing on orders so it would be at similar level as orders.  Also, as a newbie, it's typically customary to up-check answers that help you, and also click the checkmark next to the solution that worked.  This way others are not trying to answer something that is already solved.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the check mark, how do I add to your score/reputation?

Comment: Upcheck? What do I need to do to do that?

Comment: @BrianWilson, click on the http://stackoverflow.com/about about link at bottom left of page.  It shows how they work, and as up/down and answers are selected, the score/reputation for the person offering the solution is updated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    SQL>  SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME, ORDERS.ORDER_DATE,
   ORDER_LINE.NUM_ORDERED, ORDER_LINE.QUOTED_PRICE,
   SUM(Num_Ordered*Quoted_Price) AS Amt_Billed,
   PART.DESCRIPT
   FROM customer
   INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM =ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM
   INNER JOIN ORDER_LINE ON ORDERS.ORDER_NUM = ORDER_LINE.ORDER_NUM
   Inner JOIN PART ON PART.PART_NUM = ORDER_LINE.PART_NUM;
```

Line 6 was an incorrect `JOIN` statement

Line 8 was joining to wrong table

Comment: I keep getting invalid identifier:
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904: "PART"."PART_NUM": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, joins again :)

```
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER INNER JOIN ORDERS ON
```

You're missing the `ON` in `CUSTOMER` or you have an extra `INNER JOIN CUSTOMER`. Most likely the second one.

Comment: as he is selecting from `customer` in this case why would he join to `customer` again?

Comment: Good point. That would be syntactically correct but maybe not semantically correct.